# How to attach a PDF document to SOAP and send it from windows client to WCF server in C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I need to attach a PDF document and send it to the WCF server which will extract it some specific details and sends a response back to the client. Please suggest me how to acheive this in C# .Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can encode your file as base 64 using following method at client end:

```
private string EncodeFileAsBase64(string inputFileName)
    {
        byte[] binaryData;
        using (System.IO.FileStream inFile = new System.IO.FileStream(inputFileName,
                                   System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                                   System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            binaryData = new Byte[inFile.Length];
            long bytesRead = inFile.Read(binaryData, 0,
                                 (int)inFile.Length);
            inFile.Close();
        }

        // Convert the binary input into Base64 UUEncoded output. 
        string base64String;
        base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);
        return base64String;
    }
```

Now at service end you can have the physical file and you can perform whatever the operation you want. This will ensure the security aspects of the file while transmitting it over network.

Comment: Nice , good to know that it worked for you. Please mark this as an answer for you question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to upload a file to a WCF service:

Create a service contract in your interface for your Upload service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IVO_Upload
{
                [OperationContract]
                string UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request);
}

[MessageContract]
    public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
    {
        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public string FileName;
        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public long Length;
        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public string Response;

        [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
        public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (FileByteStream != null)
            {
                FileByteStream.Close();
                FileByteStream = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then implement this interface in your .svc class:

```
public class VO_eLoyalty : IVO_Upload
{

                string IVO_Upload.UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
                {
                                string _uploadFolder = "PATH_TO_SAVE_FILE";
                                string filePath = Path.Combine(_uploadFolder, request.FileName);
                                using (targetStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create,
                                FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                                {
                                                //read from the input stream in 65000 byte chunks

                                                const int bufferLen = 65000;
                                                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                                                int count = 0;
                                                while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
                                                {
                                                                // save to output stream
                                                                targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                                                }

                                                targetStream.Close();
                                                sourceStream.Close();

                                }
                                return "details"; // return whatever you need to here, or change the return type to whatever you need

                }
}
```

I presume you are happy with extracting specific details from the PDF file and returning the response?